# Flutter : How do I make BottomAppBar of buttomNavigationBar appear in every screens I have?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, screen, bottomnavigationview

I'm using BottomAppBar instead of BottomNavigationBar widget. And I want to make this bar appear in every screen I have. Again, I don't want to use BottomNavigationBar.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          width: width,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              // Home
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentScreen = HomeScreenWrapper();
                    currentTab = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: currentTab == 0 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('HOME'),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentTab == 0 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                minWidth: width / 5,
              ),

              // Dashboard
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentScreen = PointScreenWrapper();
                    currentTab = 2;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/images/dashboard.svg',
                      color: currentTab == 2 ? primaryColor : null,
                    ),
                    // Icon(
                    //   // Icons.show_chart,
                    //   Icons.dashboard,
                    //   //Icons.crop_square,
                    //   color: currentTab == 2 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    // ),
                    Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('DASHBOARD'),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentTab == 2 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                minWidth: width / 5,
              ),

              // //Make a dummy space between
              SizedBox(
                width: width / 5,
              ),

              // Score
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentScreen = ChallengeScreen();
                    currentTab = 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/images/ranking.svg',
                      color: currentTab == 1 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    // Icon(
                    //   Icons.star,
                    //   color: currentTab == 1 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    //   size: 30,
                    // ),
                    Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('RATING'),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentTab == 1 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                minWidth: width / 5,
              ),

              //
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    currentScreen = ProfileWrapper();

                    currentTab = 3;
                  });
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/images/profile.svg',
                      color: currentTab == 3 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    // Icon(
                    //   Icons.settings,
                    //   color: currentTab == 3 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    // ),
                    Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('PROFILE'),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentTab == 3 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                minWidth: width / 5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      ),
```

How do I do that? Please give me some pointer regarding this issue. I am looking forward to hearing from anyone of you. Thank you in advance...

Comment: What exactly are you asking? As long as you are in the same scaffold you will have this, otherwise, just add the same widget to every new scaffold.

Comment: Inside those screens, we have another screens. And I couldn't find a way to put a bottom navigation into those screens tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `PageView` when click on `MaterialButton` call `bottomTapped` with `index`
code snippet

```
Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        Red(),
        Blue(),
        Yellow(),
        Green(),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentTab = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentTab = index;
      pageController.animateToPage(index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double width;
  Color primaryColor = Colors.blue;

  int currentTab = 0;

  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        Red(),
        Blue(),
        Yellow(),
        Green(),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentTab = index;
    });
  }

  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentTab = index;
      pageController.animateToPage(index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: buildPageView(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          width: width,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              // Home
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  bottomTapped(0);
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: currentTab == 0 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'HOME',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentTab == 0 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                minWidth: width / 5,
              ),

              // Dashboard
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  bottomTapped(1);
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/20/20?image=9',
                      color: currentTab == 1 ? primaryColor : null,
                    ),
                    // Icon(
                    //   // Icons.show_chart,
                    //   Icons.dashboard,
                    //   //Icons.crop_square,
                    //   color: currentTab == 2 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    // ),
                    Text(
                      'DASHBOARD',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentTab == 1 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                minWidth: width / 5,
              ),

              // //Make a dummy space between
              SizedBox(
                width: width / 10,
              ),

              // Score
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  bottomTapped(2);
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/20/20?image=9',
                      color: currentTab == 2 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    // Icon(
                    //   Icons.star,
                    //   color: currentTab == 1 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    //   size: 30,
                    // ),
                    Text(
                      'RATING',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentTab == 2 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                minWidth: width / 5,
              ),

              //
              MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  bottomTapped(3);
                },
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/20/20?image=9',
                      color: currentTab == 3 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    // Icon(
                    //   Icons.settings,
                    //   color: currentTab == 3 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                    // ),
                    Text(
                      'PROFILE',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentTab == 3 ? primaryColor : Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                minWidth: width / 5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Red extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RedState createState() => _RedState();
}

class _RedState extends State<Red> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}

class Blue extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlueState createState() => _BlueState();
}

class _BlueState extends State<Blue> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
    );
  }
}

class Yellow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YellowState createState() => _YellowState();
}

class _YellowState extends State<Yellow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
    );
  }
}

class Green extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GreenState createState() => _GreenState();
}

class _GreenState extends State<Green> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Eren is right you cannot use same widget on every screen its against the flutter physics because its the scope of Scaffold field but you can use Common bottom-sheet class for every Page and pass that page context.

Answer (score 1):

In flutter a good practice would be to create a widget and use that in every scaffold. Here is an example code I am using in my application

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBottomNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  const AppBottomNavigationBar({
    Key key,
    @required this.selectedIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
          title: Text('Messages'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
          title: Text('Explore'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
          title: Text('Profile'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      onTap: (int index) {
        if (selectedIndex == index) {
          return;
        }
        if (index == 0) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
        } else if (index == 1) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/messages');
        } else if (index == 2) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/explore');
        } else if (index == 3) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/profile');
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```